# Unable to align text to the right of the row

Tags: css, flexbox, react-native

I'm looking to set the position of the date on the right of my row.

Here is the code:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 64,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  horizontalAlign: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  rowTitle: {
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    fontSize: 17,
    marginLeft: 10,
    flex: 1,
    textAlign:'center'
  },
  rowDate: {
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
  rowText: {
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    fontSize: 17,
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
  rowImage: {
    width: 35,
    height: 35,
    borderRadius: 17.5,
  },
});

renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID, _highlightRow) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => { this.rowPressed(rowData.recordID || null); }}>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Image source={ require('myImage.png') } style={styles.rowImage} />
        <View>
          <View style={styles.horizontalAlign}>
            <Text style={styles.rowTitle}>{rowData.title}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.rowDate}>{rowData.date}</Text>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.rowText}>{rowData.text}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={::this.renderRow}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

A screenshot:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you trying to have the date align to the right of the entire screen? Thanks.

Comment: Aligned to the right of the `View` (with `style={styles.row}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a flex:1 property to the view containing the rowData.title and rowData.date. I've set up an example with your data [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/mWO0LQ).

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <View style={styles.horizontalAlign}>
    <Text style={styles.rowTitle}>{rowData.title}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.rowDate}>{rowData.date}</Text>
  </View>
  <Text style={styles.rowText}>{rowData.text}</Text>
</View>
```

https://rnplay.org/apps/mWO0LQ

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with React, but in standard CSS, apply `margin-left: auto` to the date item.

You could also apply `justify-content: space-between` to the flex container which would align both flex items on opposite edges.

(These solutions assume that the line on which the flex items exist is free to extend the full width of the container.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately none of the proposals did the work. However, I noticed that `alignSelf: 'flex-end'` aligned vertically the date with the title instead of horizontally.  

Without alignSelf: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/747396ScreenShot20151110at155847.png   

With alignSelf: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/567878ScreenShot20151110at155858.png

Comment: Try `flex-grow: 1` or `flex-basis: 100%` or `width: 100%` on `View style={styles.row}` (or `horizontalAlign`), then try my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the answer from @Naber resolved my problem.

Comment: Understood. Without familiarity with React I was limited. But hopefully the flexbox info was useful.